# Why is this simple thing giving an error?

Tags: c++

This is giving an error when I input "0 0 0". In all other cases it is working fine. This code basically shows whether input 3 number sequence is AP or GP and outputs corresponding  fourth term.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a,b,c;
do{
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
     if((b*b)==(a*c)){
        cout<<"GP "<<(c*(b/a))<<endl;
    }else if((2*b)==(a+c)){
        cout<<"AP "<<(c+(b-a))<<endl;
    }
}while(a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0);

return 0;
}
```

But if I change the code using flag=0 and change it to flag = 1 when (a==0 && b==0 && c==0) it is working correctly.

Comment: You're dividing by zero.

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code divides by zero whenever `a` and `b` are `0`. That's not going to work. You need to change your loop to check the values *before* you try to use them.